# how to check strings first char in bash

Tags: bash

I want to check if a string's first char is uppercase, lowercase or anything else. I tried this code but I can't get to the last `else` although the first two conditions are false.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter var: "
read var

if [[ {$var::1 =~ [A-Z] ]]
then 
echo "UpperCase"

elif [[ {$var::1} =~ [a-z] ]]
then 
echo "LowerCase"

else 
echo "Digit or a symbol"

fi

exit
```

When I enter `1hello` I get: "LowerCase"

What am I missing here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your parameter expansions are correct. `{$var::1` evaluates to `{1hello::1`, not `1`, and `{$var::1}` likewise evaluates to `{1hello::1}`.

The expansion you want is `${var::1}`, which does expand to `1` as intended.

---

You don't need a fancy parameter expansion anyway; you can match against the first character using regular expressions alone

```
 [[ $var =~ ^[a-z] ]]
```

or pattern-matching

```
[[ $var = [a-z]* ]]
```

Regular expressions are not implicitly anchored, so you can use `^` to explicitly match the beginning of the string; the remainder of the string can be ignored.

Pattern matches are implicitly anchored to the start and end of the string, so you need `*` to match everything (if anything) that follows the initial character of the string.

Comment: Better to use `[[:lower:]]` rather than `[a-z]` for better behavior across locales; for the ones where collation order is `AaBbCcDd...Zz`, `a-z` isn't going to behave as-desired.

Answer (score 6):

You don't necessarily need to extract the first character, you can compare the whole string to a pattern.

Here, I'm using the POSIX character classes `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]` which I find more descriptive. They also handle non-ASCII letters.

Regex matching:

```sh
if   [[ $var =~ ^[[:upper:]] ]]; then echo starts with an upper
elif [[ $var =~ ^[[:lower:]] ]]; then echo starts with a lower
else                                  echo does not start with a letter
fi
```

With shell glob patterns -- within `[[...]]` the `==` operator does *pattern matching* not just string equality

```sh
if   [[ $var == [[:upper:]]* ]]; then echo starts with an upper
elif [[ $var == [[:lower:]]* ]]; then echo starts with a lower
else                                  echo does not start with a letter
fi
```

A `case` statement would work here as well

```sh
case "$var" in
    [[:upper:]]*) echo starts with an upper ;;
    [[:lower:]]*) echo starts with a lower ;;
               *) echo does not start with a letter ;;
esac
```